# Issue in Google Sheets with a combination of SUM, ARRAYFORMULA, SUMIF and "not equal to" operator

Tags: google-sheets, operators, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

EDIT: Reading "not equal to" operator cannot be used with SUMIF. I’ll leave the question open in case someone comes with an alternate function to obtain the result I was looking for.

I have a formula that SUM hours worked in a month on two projects. In Sheet1, on each row, are the number of hours worked, in a month, on a specific task. Associated with the tasks are corresponding IDs. In Sheet2, some of the task IDs are listed in one of two columns, column A and column B, corresponding to ProjectA and ProjectB, so that for each project I have the list of tasks related to it. In Sheet3, the formula aggregates the hours worked on both projects, associated with multiple tasks, and excludes the hours worked on tasks not associated with a project. Does it makes sens? The formula looks like this:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('Sheet1'!B5:B;"="&{Sheet2!A2:B};'Sheet1'!C5:C)))
```

This formula works just fine, and gives the following result:

80:45:00 (hours)

But when I try to aggregate the remaining worked hours, on tasks not associated with ProjectA or ProjectB, by using instead of the "equal to" operator (=) the "not equal to" operator (<>), to exclude hours worked on tasks which IDs are associated with either project, the resulting formula:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('Sheet1'!B5:B;"<>"&{Sheet2!A2:B};'Sheet1'!C5:C)))
```

Does not provide the expected result at all.

I get:

167251:45:00

Instead of:

3:00:00 hours

(!)

Copy of the spreadsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hr4z_2pZNOWpJI9i6XXYdXB4_O3KXqZGzvfYpLB0ZRQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Help would be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Here is a blank sheet created specifically for this question.  It will be significantly easier to help if you share sample data that accurately represents your real sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NO_BfDw1nJe1nJ9VvWODYf6pzo9N9za0zgz2PwUYzfI/edit

Comment: Hi @MattKing thank you. I did put a copy of the data, but for a reason unknown to me, non of the formulas seems to work in the sheet you provided.

Comment: I’ve shared a copy of my spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hr4z_2pZNOWpJI9i6XXYdXB4_O3KXqZGzvfYpLB0ZRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `Not equal to` must be replaced by` countif` to globalize the criteria instead of checking one by one. If you expand the function with the `<>` operator in a worksheet, you can see that each row will be added 3 times if you have 3 projects except when the project id matches.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, maybe that would help to explain the number I get with `SUMIF` and `not equal to` (167251:45:00)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julien, try

```
=sum(arrayformula(if(COUNTIF(livrables!$A$2:$D;'résumé'!$B$5:$B);0;'résumé'!C$5:C)))
```

you can use the same formula for C7

```
=sum(arrayformula(if(COUNTIF(livrables!$A$2:$D;'résumé'!$B$5:$B);'résumé'!C$5:C;0)))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0daTbk3S8yIH48ijk250ZnxTIf7DoLO8SEyolaWrRs/edit?usp=sharing

#### Explanation:

Countif is used to compare the data, if they match I take the sum in C7, if they don't match I take the sum in C8, that's why 0 and sum are swapped.

#### Reference:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Mike Steelson for your answer. And thank you for your suggestion on C7. Accepted! But what is happening here? The zero, when changing place, reverse the criteria?

Comment: Countif is used to compare the data, if they match I take the sum in C7, if they don't match I take the sum in C8, that's why 0 and sum are swapped!

Answer (score 0):

So far I was unable to solve it the way you were doing it. But, couldn't you sum up all the hours from the months and then subtract the value you got previously from the working formula?

Here's a copy of your Sheet with this suggestion done [Exemple](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ebCVoUa8FqKnH4poetjp20e_n5JmglFMCLaS_g7wgyY/edit#gid=1602415192&range=C8)

Comment: Not really the most elegant way to do it, but I guess it might work for you.

Comment: Hi Otávio Teixeira, thank you for your answer! The stop-gap solution I am using right now comes down to something similar, to circumvent the problem, but it does not solve it. Actually, this is the formula I intend to use to double check the result obtained with the proper formula.

Comment: Got it. Hope you find a solution that fits this problem then. I might give it another try later.

Comment: Reading it cannot be done with SUMIF function.